# Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, cordova, build, resources, cross-platform

I try to build a project with cordova. But it don't seems to find the android resources, I get much errors like this one:

> C:..\uphair\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml:231: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.

Like so I didnt have android tools installed, but I double checked that they were installed correctly on SDK manager from API 19 to API 25.

I have also an error saying `Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt`

Anyone have some help please ? I'm stuck :(

**[EDIT]** Solved, there was a Android SDK version problem in the gradle.build of my app and the facebook-connect-plugin one, all fine now.

Comment: how did you solve it.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Just put the same version number on both gradle.build, the one of your app, and the one in your facebook-plugin directory.